# Jinja2 Network Automation - increasing a variable (subnet +1)

Tags: python, templates, networking, jinja2, cisco

First of all, I am a network engineer learning a bit of coding and attempting to evolve using this relatively new tech. I have searched the interwebs for many hours regarding the below question but most search results include Ansible which i don't want (at the moment).

I am using a python/jinja2 script which generates a configuration based on VARs called confplate: see https://github.com/verbosemode/confplate - i have done some testing and it works great. Super easy and fast.

However, I'm trying to use a variable (a network address) and increment it within the Jinja2 template to set an IP address.

See below Jinja2 snippet:

```
ip dhcp pool WLAN01
network {{ vlan400_network }} 255.255.255.0
domain-name abc.xyz
default-router {{ vlan400_network + 1 }}
lease 0 1
```

`vlan400_network = 172.29.50.0`

I want the default-router to be `172.29.50.1` - of course i cannot increment it using the above snippet.

Do i need to use regular expressions for this? It does not seem very easy using solely Jinja2. 
My preference is to get this done using Python/Jinja2 only. Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you discovered, you're not going to get very far with generating configurations for network devices if you just rely on Jinja2's default filters.

You have to write your own custom filters (in Python) and use them in your template files.

For the example that you have, do this:

**Step 1: Design the template**

I am going to provide the vlan network as a CIDR specification:

```
./confplate.py template.txt vlan400_network=21.22.23.0/24
```

As you can see, this is intuitive and flexible: if you like you can change the network to `21.22.23.192/26` and things will continue to work just fine, as we will shortly see.

The template for this looks like:

```
ip dhcp pool WLAN01
 network {{ vlan400_network | network_from_cidr }}
 domain-name abc.xyz
 default-router {{ vlan400_network | gateway_from_cidr }}
 lease 0 1
```

where `network_from_cidr` and `gateway_from_cidr` are custom Jinja2 filters that we will shortly create.

The idea is that the `network_from_cidr` filter will take a string like "21.22.23.0/24" and return the string "21.22.23.0 255.255.255.0". Likewise, the `gateway_from_cidr` filter will take the string "21.22.23.0/24" and return "21.22.23.1" (i.e. the first non-zero host address in the subnet).

**Step 2: Write the Python code for the custom filters**

Create a file named `custom_filters.py` and put in the following code:

```
import ipaddress

def network_from_cidr (cidr):
    ipn = ipaddress.ip_network(unicode(cidr), strict=True)
    return '{} {}'.format(ipn.network_address, ipn.netmask)

def gateway_from_cidr (cidr):
    ipn = ipaddress.ip_network(unicode(cidr), strict=True)
    # By convention, the gateway has the first non-zero address in the subnet
    first_address = list(ipn.hosts())[0]
    return first_address
```

The code uses the [ipaddress module](https://cpython-test-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/ipaddress.html). As you can see, we define two functions, one for each of the custom filters we want to create. The functions take one argument, which is the string that precedes the `|` in the template.

**Step 3: Tell confplate.py about your custom filters**

Somewhere at the beginning of `confplate.py` write `import custom_filters`.

You then have to say:

```
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(self.templatepath), undefined=StrictUndefined)

# Load our custom filters
env.filters['network_from_cidr'] = custom_filters.network_from_cidr
env.filters['gateway_from_cidr'] = custom_filters.gateway_from_cidr
```

at appropriate points in the code (in confplate.py you actually have to do this twice, once in the `get_template_vars` function, and once in `render_template`)

**Test**

```
./confplate.py template.txt vlan400_network=21.22.23.0/24
ip dhcp pool WLAN01
 network 21.22.23.0 255.255.255.0
 domain-name abc.xyz
 default-router 21.22.23.1
 lease 0 1

./confplate.py template.txt vlan400_network=21.22.23.192/26
ip dhcp pool WLAN01
 network 21.22.23.192 255.255.255.192
 domain-name abc.xyz
 default-router 21.22.23.193
 lease 0 1
```

Comment: I have to say.. what a wonderful answer and explanation. Thank you. I will test this later today and mark it as an answer..

Comment: I am having a problem with the the templatepath (i think)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./confplate.py", line 405, in <module>
    main()
  File "./confplate.py", line 387, in main
    print(tpl.render_template())
  File "./confplate.py", line 139, in render_template
    tpl = env.get_template(self.templatename)
   return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/home/ajay/py3-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)

Comment: Did you follow my instructions in Step 3: "... _in confplate.py you actually have to do this twice_ ..."

Comment: Yes i did, defined it right under 
"def get_template_vars" and "def render_template"
Last error shows: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'network_from_cidr'. It is frustrating that i cannot figure this one out by myself haha..

Comment: I will try to figure this out at a later time. I am now using Ansible with the ipaddr filter which makes it easier for my current skill level. Thanks so much!